# FosMessageBundle: finding route for creating a new message

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed FOSMessageBundle. I think my installation is correct. No error on doctrine:generate:entities neither on doctrine:schema:update.

I see in ressources/routing.xml there is this route:

```
<route id="fos_message_thread_new" path="/new">
    <default key="_controller">FOSMessageBundle:Message:newThread</default>
</route>
```

My problem is I don't understand how to run this route ...

I tried:

```
http://localhost/mySuperProject/web/app_dev.php/new
http://localhost/mySuperProject/web/app_dev.php/new/thread
http://localhost/mySuperProject/web/app_dev.php/thread/new
http://localhost/mySuperProject/web/app_dev.php/thread
```

I have also tried to run the same routes replacing "thread" in the url by "message" but no route got found

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try use the `debug:router` command. It should shows you details for the route (including the full path of the route).

`app/console debug:router fos_message_thread_new`

Comment: Thank you my friend this helped me to find the route. The route to run is /optional_routing_prefix/new ... I suppose now I have to change the prefix: 'optional_routing_prefix' by my own in a config file. 
So have a good day !